# Dynamic CSS generation doesn't work in Rails4

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The following code isn't working, I need to create css class like 'read-more-105','read-more-106' etc, according to tale.id's vale

```
<%= simple_format truncate(plot.description, length: char_counter){link_to "Read More",'', class: 'read-more-<% tale.id %>'} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need string interpolation here:

```
<%= simple_format truncate(plot.description, length: char_counter){link_to "Read More",'', class: "read-more-#{tale.id}" } %>
```

As you can not have `<% %>` inside a `<% %>` or `<%= %>`.