# Dynamic css classes inside embedded ruby

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

A Persona has persona_id of either 1, 2 or 3. I want to assign a class type of either persona-1-button, persona-2-button or persona-3-button inside the embedded ruby. The following code is not working and I don't know why:

```
<% current_user.personas.each do |persona| %>
  <% foo = persona.persona_id.to_s %>
  <% bar = "persona-" + foo + "-button" %>
  <%= link_to "Persona", persona_path(persona), class: "btn btn-medium bar" %>
<% end %>
```

I didn't do it the follwoing way because it seems you can't have a <%=%> inside a <%=%>:

```
<% current_user.personas.each do |persona| %>
  <%= link_to "Persona", persona_path(persona), class: "btn btn-medium persona<%=persona.persona_id%>button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic CSS generation doesn't work in Rails4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604648/dynamic-css-generation-doesnt-work-in-rails4)

Comment: The problem has already solved in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74660394/20669402)

Comment: The problem has already been solved in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74660394/20669402). please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/74660394/20669402

Answer (score 4):

You have it almost correct already.

The thing you need to realise is that when you're inside the `<%`/`%>` tags, you're in a Ruby context. That means, that the `"..."` creates a `String` inside which you can use regular Ruby string interpolation, like this:

```
  <%= link_to "Persona", persona_path(persona), class: "btn btn-medium #{bar}" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're placing a variable in Ruby context where you are bound by the rules of Ruby, not ERB. And in Ruby it's done using string interpolation:

```
<%= link_to "Persona", persona_path(persona), class: "btn btn-medium #{bar}" %>
```

Comment: Thank you chaps, appreciate it.