# Can I nest a ruby embed symbol <%= %> inside another <%= %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-7

I want to use a helper Method inside link_to tag as follows

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path, class:"nav-link <%= activeLink('home') %>" %>
```

This is my helper method

```
def activeLink(action_name)
    if controller.action_name == action_name
      "active"
    end
  end
```

I am getting error saying;

ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in PagesController#about

I want that helper method to check the current action name and
set the 'active' CSS class if current action matches the input action name

Comment: No. And you don't need it in the first place. You can just use string interpolation - `"nav-link %{ activeLink('home') }"`.

Comment: Can you? Kind of (you would have to pass the inner one to ERB again). Do you need to in your case. No.  See @max's comment except change that `%` to a `#`

Comment: @engineersmnky repeated exposure to JS rots the brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use nested `<%= ... %>` notation? No.

However, what you're looking for is a form of [string interpolation](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/07/ruby-string-concatenation/). As mentioned in the comments Ruby variables can be converted to strings in a couple ways (full details outlined in the linked guide).

The primary method you'll see is by using `#{}` within a string ie `"This is my string #{ruby_variable}"`.

Which means you could use the following:

```
my_string = "World!"

hello_world_string = "Hello #{my_string}"

hello_world_string
=> "Hello World!"
```